# I don’t receive any emails in an specific mail account

Tags: email, cpanel

I’m having a problem with an email account.
We are using Cpanel, and I don’t receive any emails in an specific mail account. I use webmail ( www.domainexample.com:2095 ) . I tried on IE and Firefox.

But when I try to access this email account from other computers in the same network… it works just great! So the problem is specifically on my computer. I tried to open other emails accounts with the same domain in my computer, and they also work.

So the problem is only on my computer and only with this e-mail account.

I clean the cookies and the .temp files. But … nothing.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Since it seems to be a webmail, what do you mean when you say you don't receive emails on your computer, but on others? The page is not accessible, or it's an empty inbox on one computer and not the others?

Comment: @Gnoupi it's an empty inbox on one computer and not the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a strange issue. This isn't an answer, but things to try:

I would assume this is a security issue or firewall issue or antivirus setting some where - could even be a web formatting/render issue - are you on the same browsers as others - do you have java installed (if required)?.

Can you disable your antivirus and try (only do this if you are happy and confident to do so!)

Maybe within IE you can add the website to the list of trusted sites?

Or within IE, change the privacy settings?

Comment: Is not an antivirus or firewall issue. I've disable it. And other emails address with the same domain are working just fine in my computer. strange indeed. And I try it on IE and Firefox.

Comment: When you log on, do you get a short or a very long URL in the address bar like www.domainname.com/email?user=xxxencode=absdfjsaf  etc

Comment: Can you right click in the inbox area and view source to see if the HTML can see anything (or not)?

Comment: I know unlikely, but can you completely delete your history etc in-case it's some how cached? CCleaner is good for this: http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER

Comment: Did CCleaner work?

Comment: Not really. but the email account works on ms outlook. Is not a solution, but is good enough! :)